# Paypal - Selling a digital product attached to a specific user?

Tags: php, paypal, metadata

I'm confused by the array of Paypal APIs and options out there.  Can someone help me to identify a good starting point for a virtual/digital product option that can have some custom meta data associated with it?  Here are my requirements:

- I'm selling in-app credits/currency
- I'm using PHP to integrate with Paypal
- Each purchase must be able to attach some data (for example, a user ID and a product ID from my database) that will be passed back to me so I can identify which user purchased which product, so once it is verified with Paypal, I'll know how to give the digital product to the buyer.

I assumed that "Digital Goods for Express Checkout" would do the trick, since it seems designed for online/virtual/digital types of products.  However, I'm having trouble finding a way to pass through the user ID and product ID with this option.  I also looked at the example and library at https://github.com/thenbrent/paypal-digital-goods-php-examples but I don't see an obvious way attach this dynamic meta data.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only want one id. Nothing more is needed. Before processing the order, you bind the id with your meta data (in a database like MySQL).

Then in the listener you can pull out the data using the id.

Hope it helped

Comment: Ok, I can certainly use one ID.  But how do I provide this ID to the API so it can be retrieved later?  Does it look for a value under a specific name?  I couldn't easily find a reference to this in the docs.  Thanks.